# C++ unordered_map fail when used with a vector as key

Tags: c++, qt, vector, c++11, unordered-map

Background: I am comming from the Java world and I am fairly new to C++ or Qt.

In order to play with unordered_map, I have written the following simple program:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
typedef std::vector<float> floatVector;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    floatVector c(10);
    floatVector b(10);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        c[i] = i + 1;
        b[i] = i * 2;
    }
    
    std::unordered_map<floatVector, int> map;
    
    map[b] = 135;
    map[c] = 40;
    map[c] = 32;
  
    std::cout << "b -> " << map[b] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c -> " << map[c] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Contains? -> " << map.size() << std::endl;
    
    return a.exec();
}
```

Unfortunately, I am running into the folowing error which isn't inspiring. There is not even a line number.

> :-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Any idea of the origin of the problem?

Comment: You need a hash function that takes a `vector<float>`

Comment: This isn't a runtime failure.

Comment: @SethCarnegie That was what I though the problem was comming too. However, it seems to me that a class as basic as vector should have a default hash function. If it isn't the case, could you explain me how to provide one or point me to some material. Thank you!

Comment: Valid and interesting question, but I don't see a use case where it will be clever to use a list as a key in a map.

Comment: @UmNyobe The int is the result of a heavy computation from which the vector is the input. The result once computed need to be access many times and quickly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

§23.2.5, paragraph 3, says:

> Each unordered associative container is parameterized by `Key`, by a function object type `Hash` that meets the Hash requirements (17.6.3.4) and acts as a hash function for argument values of type `Key`, and by a binary predicate `Pred` that induces an equivalence relation on values of type `Key`.

Using `vector<float>` as `Key` and not providing explicit hash and equivalence predicate types means the default `std::hash<vector<float>>` and `std::equal_to<vector<float>>` will be used.

The `std::equal_to` for the equivalence relation is fine, because there is an operator `==` for vectors, and that's what `std::equal_to` uses.

There is however, no `std::hash<vector<float>>` specialization, and that's probably what the linker error you didn't show us says. You need to provide your own hasher for this to work.

An easy way of writing such an hasher is to use [`boost::hash_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_range):

```
template <typename Container> // we can make this generic for any container [1]
struct container_hash {
    std::size_t operator()(Container const& c) const {
        return boost::hash_range(c.begin(), c.end());
    }
};
```

Then you can use:

```
std::unordered_map<floatVector, int, container_hash<floaVector>> map;
```

Of course, if you need different equality semantics in the map you need to define the hash and equivalence relation appropriately.

---

<sub>1. However, avoid this for hashing unordered containers, as different orders will produce different hashes, and the order in unordered container is not guaranteed.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much this indeed solved my problem.

Note for people that would have the same problem:
to use boost::hash_range you need to #include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

Comment: @user1162647 : That's literally the first thing on that doc page. ;-]

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes : If you're still watching, the docs in that page say: "hash_range is sensitive to the order of the elements so it wouldn't be appropriate to use this with an unordered container." Does that suggest the above usage is wrong?

Comment: @Dilip I think what that means is that calling `hash_range (unordered_container)` is a bad idea because it can produce different results each time.

Comment: @hash3r That's because map uses red and black trees at the backend and is not concerned with the kind of data stored. Whereas, unordered_map essentially needs a hash function. And it can only be calculated once the kind of data stored in the vector is ascertained.

Comment: Note that you can use `boost::hash` provided by `boost/container_hash/hash.hpp` directly. No need to write a custom hasher. Documentation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html. (In 2012, it was in `boost/functional/hash.hpp`.)

Answer (score 24):

I found R. Martinho Fernandes's answer unsuitable for competitive programming since most of the times you have to deal with a provided IDE and cannot use an external library such as `boost`. You can use the following method if you'd like to make the best of STL.

As already stated above, you just need to write a hash function. And it should specialize for the kind of data stored in your vector. The following hash function assumes `int` type data:

```
struct VectorHasher {
    int operator()(const vector<int> &V) const {
        int hash = V.size();
        for(auto &i : V) {
            hash ^= i + 0x9e3779b9 + (hash << 6) + (hash >> 2);
        }
        return hash;
    }
};
```

Note that you can use any kind of operation to generate a hash. You just need to be creative so that collisions are minimized. For example, `hash^=V[i]`, `hash|=V[i]`, `hash+=V[i]*V[i]` or even `hash+=(V[i]<<i)*(V[i]<<i)*(V[i]<<i)` are all valid until of course, your hash doesn't overflows.

Finally to use this hash function with your `unordered_map`, initialize it as follows:

```
unordered_map<vector<int>,string,VectorHasher> hashMap;
```

Comment: Shouldn’t the second template parameter be `int` instead of `bool`?

Comment: @wcochran It works with any permitted data structure/type(map, vector, set, queue, stack, int, float, ...etc). Depends on your use case.

Comment: If you are not bothering with a sensible hash, why not go all the way with `template <typename T> struct AnyHasher { int operator()(const T &) { return 0; } }` ?

Comment: @Caleth do you think it is sensible enough now?