# Trouble creating custom hash function unordered_map?

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map, hash-function

I wanted to create a custom hash function for an unordered map. I found this question: [C++ unordered_map fail when used with a vector as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405030/c-unordered-map-fail-when-used-with-a-vector-as-key) and found that if you use a vector as a key in an unordered map, you need to create your own hash function. I experimented copying the hash function written as so:

```
template <typename Container> 
struct container_hash {
    std::size_t operator()(Container const& c) const {
        return boost::hash_range(c.begin(), c.end());
    }
};
```

But when I try to create an unordered_map with my keys as a vector of ints like so:,

```
unordered_map<vector<int>, int, container_hash<vector<int>>> hash;
```

I get an issue saying that:

```
error: declaration of ‘struct std::hash<std::vector<int> >’
```

I have tried other ways to include the container_hash function into the implementation of my unordered_map by trying things like

```
unordered_map<vector<int>, int, container_hash> hash;
```

But again I get another error saying:

```
type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Hash, class _Pred, class _Alloc> class std::unordered_map’
```

I'm really not sure how to get around this, if anyone could help me that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: What compiler? Both gcc and clang [accept](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4988e4aad76243f) your first definition.

Comment: I am trying to write a program using MPI so I was using the mpicxx compiler @Praetorian

Comment: See if it'll compile the code I linked to, if not it might be problem with that compiler.

Comment: @Praetorian interestingly enough it does compile. I don't think I have anything different from what you had written in the code you linked either.

Comment: @Praetorian Ah nevermind. I found the issue. It was somewhere else in my code. I apologize and thank you so much for helping me out with this.

Comment: Probably the insufficient spacing for ">>" in template closing brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code [compiles just fine](http://ideone.com/8Z99eq):

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

template <typename Container>
struct container_hash {
    std::size_t operator()(Container const& c) const {
    return boost::hash_range(c.begin(), c.end());
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::unordered_map
        <std::vector <int>, int,
         container_hash <std::vector  <int> > > foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Your problem is likely elsewhere.