# where should I put the specialized std::hash for user defined type

Tags: c++11, hash, unordered-set, user-defined

I searched many pages, and I think I have known how to write the std::hash. But I don't know where to put it.

An example is presented here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash .

However, I defined my type `Instance` in namespace `ca` in file `instance_management.h`. I want to use `unordered_set<Instance>` in the same file in another class `InstanceManager`. So I write the following code:

```
namespace std
{
    template <> struct hash<ca::Instance>
    {
        size_t operator()(const ca::Instance & instance) const
        {
            std::size_t seed = 0;
            // Some hash value calculation here.
            return seed;
        }
    };
} // namespace std
```

But where should I put it? I tried many locations but all failed.

I am using visual studio 2013. I tried to put the previous code in some locations but all failed to compile it.

```
// location 1

namespace ca
{
    class Instance {...}
    class InstanceManager
    {
        // ... some other things.
        private unordered_set<Instance>;
    }
}

// location 2
```

Comment: What's wrong with putting it in `instance_management.h`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone.

I have found the reason and solved the problem somehow: visual studio accepted the `InstanceHash` when I was defining `instances_`. Since I was changing the use of `set` to `unordered_set`, I forgot to specify `InstanceHash` when I tried to get the `const_iterator`, so this time the compiler tried to use the `std::hash<>` things and failed. But the compiler didn't locate the line using `const_iterator`, so I mistakenly thought it didn't accept `InstanceHash` when I was defining `instances_`.

I also tried to specialize the `std::hash<>` for class Instance. However, this specialization requires at least the declaration of class `ca::Instance` and some of its member functions to calculate the hash value. After this specialization, the definition of class `ca::InstanceManage` will use it.

I now generally put declarations and implementations of almost every classes and member functions together. So, the thing I need to do is probably to split the `ca` namespace scope to 2 parts and put the `std{ template <> struct hash<ca::Instance>{...}}` in the middle.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn The proposal to put template specialization to the std namespace comes from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157937/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered Also, if I don't put the specialization to the std namespace, I would need to specify the `InstanceHash` every time I tried to get a iterator as like:

Comment: as like:`unordered_set<Instance, InstanceHash>::const_iterator iterator = instances_.find(...)` I wonder which is the better programming practice: put the template specialization in std or not.

Comment: This is why classes usually start by defining a bunch of types using `typedef`. The better programming practice is definitely NOT to put it in the std namespace.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways.

### Specializing `std::hash`

In your code make sure that your `std::hash<Instance>` specialization is preceded immediately by the `Instance` class definition, and followed by the use of the `unordered_set` container that uses it.

```
namespace ca
{
    class Instance {...};

}

namespaces std {

    template<> hash<Instance> { ... };

}

namespace ca {

    class InstanceManager
    {
        // ... some other things.
        private unordered_set<Instance>;
    }
}
```

One drawback is that you can have funny name lookup interference when passing a `std::hash<ca::Instance>` to other functions. The reason is that the associated namespace (`ca`) of all the template arguments of `std::hash` can be used during name lookup (ADL). Such errors are a bit rare, but if they occur they can be hard to debug.

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8157937/819272) for more details.

### Passing your hash to `unordered_set`

```
struct MyInstanceHash { ... };

using MyUnorderedSet = std:unordered_set<Instance, MyInstanceHash>;
```

Here, you simply pass your own hash function to the container and be done with it. The drawback is that you have to explicitly type your own container.

### Using `hash_append`

Note, however, there is the [**N3980**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html) Standard proposal is currently pending for review. This proposal features a much superior design that uses a universal hash function that takes an arbitrary byte stream to be hashed by its template parameter (the actual hashing algorithm)

```
template <class HashAlgorithm>
struct uhash
{
    using result_type = typename HashAlgorithm::result_type;

    template <class T>
    result_type
    operator()(T const& t) const noexcept
    {
        HashAlgorithm h;
        using std::hash_append;
        hash_append(h, t);
        return static_cast<result_type>(h);
    }
};
```

A user-defined class X then has to provide the proper `hash_append` through which it presents itself as a byte stream, ready to be hashed by the univeral hasher.

```
class X
{
    std::tuple<short, unsigned char, unsigned char> date_;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>                data_;

public:
    // ...
    friend bool operator==(X const& x, X const& y)
    {
        return std::tie(x.date_, x.data_) == std::tie(y.date_, y.data_);
    }

    // Hook into the system like this
    template <class HashAlgorithm>
    friend void hash_append(HashAlgorithm& h, X const& x) noexcept
    {
        using std::hash_append;
        hash_append(h, x.date_);
        hash_append(h, x.data_);
    }
}
```

For more details, see the presentation by the author @HowardHinnant at CppCon14 ([slides](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/tree/master/Presentations/Types%20Don't%20Know%20%23), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Njjp_MJsgt8)). Full source code by both the [**author**](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/hash_append) and [Bloomberg](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/master/groups/bsl/bslh/doc/bslh.txt) is available.

Comment: I would upvote +10 because this is awesome, but it doesn't really answer the OP does it?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn there is working code that implements this and avoids the use of `std::hash` entirely. In your answer, the statement  `H(e.src) ^ H(e.dst)` is the weak link. It could destroy all the nice properties of your hash function.

Comment: @TemplateRex Actually, I don't know what does "Standard proposal" means. Does it means the proposal will be C++ standard some day? How about the compiler support? Will the VC++ support it?

Comment: @TemplateRex I tried `using std::hash_append;` in visual studio 2013 and pressed `F1` key for `hash_append`. The online document system didn't find information about it. So I think this feature is not supported by visual studio. What c++ library do you find this feature in?

Comment: @JohnSmith just download hash_append.h from hinnant's github (see link in answer). You might want to upgrade to VC++ 2015 because of the c++14 requirements. This library could become part of the C++ Standard, but so far it is only proposed, not decided

Comment: @TemplateRex Why would you say the xor is the weak link? I appreciate that your solution is elegant and less verbose, but it is not essentially different from hashing the contents of an instance manually in a separate function object, it is not standard as of now, it is certainly more complex and definitely not compatible with either c++11 or VS2013 which the OP is using.. I still like your post, but it is both out of scope and incompatible with the apparent programming skills of the OP.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I'd recommend that you read N3980. It solves the problem of combining hashes of different sub-objects. Even if you have a perfect and great hash function (with proven distributional properties), simply doing `h(x) ^ h(y)` will destroy these nice properties. Instead, you want to be able to concanate the byte streams of the subjects into the (likely stateful) hash algorithm. BTW, SO answers are not just aimed at the OP but at the public at large, which is C++ programmers. And using hash_append.h from GitHub does not require that much skill.

Answer (score 1):

Do not specialise `std::hash`, instead write your own hash function object (see `Edge_Hash` below) and declare your `unordered_set` with two template arguments.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>

namespace foo
{
    // an edge is a link between two nodes
    struct Edge
    {
        size_t src, dst;
    };

    // this is an example of symmetric hash (suitable for undirected graphs)
    struct Edge_Hash
    {
        inline size_t operator() ( const Edge& e ) const
        {
            static std::hash<size_t> H;
            return H(e.src) ^ H(e.dst);
        }
    };

    // this keeps all edges in a set based on their hash value
    struct Edge_Set
    {
        // I think this is what you're trying to do?
        std::unordered_set<Edge,Edge_Hash> edges;
    };
}

int main()
{
    foo::Edge_Set e;
}
```

Related posts are, eg:

- [Inserting in unordered_set using custom hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869066/inserting-into-unordered-set-with-custom-hash-function)
- [Trouble creating custom hash function unordered_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355522/trouble-creating-custom-hash-function-unordered-map)

Comment: I am developing a C++ library code. So, there is no main() in the instance_management.h file. And I have to try to put everything in namespace, including the class Instance and InstanceManager which uses unordered_set<Instance >. However, it's said on many pages that it's encouraged to put specialized std::hash<> for user defined type in std namespace. I wrote the code snippet and tried to put it some where in the same file but couldn't successfully compile the instance_management.h file.

Comment: When I put your code in a separate .h file, visual studio compiled it successfully. However, when I did the same way for my code and use ` private:
  unordered_set<Instance, InstanceHash> instances_;`, I get errors like:

Comment: errors like: `error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.`and `see reference to class template instantiation 'std::hash<_Kty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=ca::Instance
1>          ]`. It seems the compiler didn't accept the InstanceHash specified by me.