# Simple hash table with vector

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

As i understood correctly , implementing hash table , is calculating index based on inputed string , and returning it directly making it simple key - value storage.

So simple hash function could look something like

```
int hash( string name ){

    int index = 0;
    int hash = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < name.length() ;i++){
        hash += (int)name[i];
    }
    index = sizeOfArray % hash;
}
```

SizeOfArray is array of pointers with predefined size. If this index does not exists it creates it. But how i implement it with vectors?

Vector does not have predefined size. An they grow automaticly. So calling sizeOfArray % hash will change everytim vector will grow.

What is logic behind has tables? Whats the best method to calculate index even with growing vector / array?

Comment: Why not simply use an array of string *? And, since there may be collisions, you're better of using an array of linked lists (or vectors) of string, since multiple strings have to be attachable to one hash key. By the way, maybe you make this just to learn from, which is very useful. But hash keys are the basis of many STL datastructures which come with your compiler.

Comment: Learning about hash-tables are a good idea, but don't implement your own for anything but learning purposes, not when there's [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: I am creating thins in order to learn , i want to store an structure at index , which will hold multiple data.

Comment: You can tell a vector to be a specific size and they do not grow automatically unless you call a function that makes them grow.

Comment: As for your underlying vector, it *can't* change. While a hash-table itself is of variable length, the number of *buckets* (the elements in the vector) has to remain constant, or the hashing function will not work, as otherwise the same entry in the hash-table will give you different indexes depending on the size. Instead the usual way is to have each entry in the underlying vector by a *list*, and items with the same index (same hash) are put into this list.

Comment: Also, your index calculation is wrong, it should the the other way around: `hash % sizeOfArray`.

Comment: If you want a hash function with a growing sized array, I suggest using linear hashing.

Comment: I would like to have less then linear complexity.

Comment: As Joachim said, traditional hash functions have to assume the hash table is fixed sized, otherwise your hash function will return different results and won't work correctly.

Comment: Linear hashing doesn't result in linear complexity for the lookup, it's still constant time.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to use a vector as key in your table. If so, here is a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405030/c-unordered-map-fail-when-used-with-a-vector-as-key) explaining how to use `std::vector` as hash key. You can see the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_ran_idm45507096028608) for details (though it's a pain to read)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `vector<list<string>>` as the underlying data structure for the hash table.
Also, you got the index calculation wrong; instead of `sizeOfArray % hash`, it should be the other way round.

```
vector<list<string>> hash_table;
const size_t hash_table_size = 100;
hash_table.resize(hash_table_size);

int hash( string name ){
    int index = 0;
    int hash = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < name.length() ;i++){
        hash += (int)name[i];
    }

    index = hash % hash_table.size();
    hash_table[index].push_back(name);
}
```

Comment: The OP should find this helpful, but - nitpicking - it shouldn't be the hash function actually inserting data in the table: a seperate insert function that calls `hash` ought to do that (and likely also do the `% hash_table.size()`).  Further, you shouldn't `push_back` to the bucket without checking whether the `name` already appears therein.  But, the OP can sort those things out I'm sure....